# IIS8 HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-8

I'm trying to move my website to another host, a shared hosting, and I keep getting this message:

> Detailed Error Information: Module
>   AspNetInitializationExceptionModule Notification     BeginRequest
>   Handler      ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0 Error Code
>   0x00000000 Requested URL     http://1.3144.co.il:80/ Physical Path
>   h:\root\home\picsize-001\www\3144clubmember Logon Method     Not yet
>   determined Logon User    Not yet determined

I've tried many things but nothing seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like either your host doesn't support .net 4.5 or you don't have it enabled.

Things to check in your hosts control panel:

You have enabled .net 4.5
It's running in integrated mode and not classic pipeline

Comment: I have another website running on the same host. It's supprt .net 4.5, it's enable and running in integrated mode. The website 3144.co.il is working just fine, only the subdomain not working.

Comment: All sounds like you haven't configured your host correctly. Does your site run locally ok? if so, 100% config issue. Too little info to really help anymore than that.

Comment: It's not run locally. My client gave this code from his developer. When I'm trying to run the website locally I get this error: 

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 
Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: You have many problems here. That one says that you have code wanting to use Entity Framework but its not installed. In your solution run nuget installer `Install-Package EntityFramework` -